# history expansion in zsh

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

according to the doc, `!!` should expand to the last command when hit `<tab>` after it. However, this is not the case for my setup (I used default oh-my-zsh). Here is an example:

`$ echo 1
1
$ echo 2
2
$ !!<tab>
$ echo 1`

Moreover, `!#` does not expand to what are input in the current line. Instead, it expands to the last command

`$ echo 1
1
$ echo 2
2
$ echo 3 !#<tab>
$ echo 3 echo 2`

Is there any option controls this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the default `oh-my-zsh` completion settings on [github](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/completion.zsh) and it look like parameter expansion is not enabled out of the box. According to `oh-my-zsh` [documentation](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#custom-plugins-and-themes) any overrides should go into `custom/` directory, in files ending with `*.zsh`. Getting parameter expansion to work should be as simple as dropping there a file with something like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete
```

The completer function you're looking for is called `_expand`, here is what `man zshcompsys` has to say about it:

```
_expand

This completer function does not really perform completion, but instead 
checks if the word on the command line is eligible for
expansion and, if it is, gives detailed control over how this
expansion is done. For this to happen, the completion system needs to
be invoked with complete-word, not expand-or-complete (the default
binding for TAB), as otherwise the string will be expanded by the
shell's internal mechanism before the completion system is started.
Note also this completer should be called before the _complete
completer function.

The tags used when generating expansions are all-expansions for the
string containing all possible expansions, expansions when adding the
possible expansions as single matches and original when adding the
original string from the line. The order in which these strings are
generated, if at all, can be controlled by the group-order and
tag-order styles, as usual.

The format string for all-expansions and for expansions may contain
the sequence '%o' which will be replaced by the original string from
the line.

The kind of expansion to be tried is controlled by the substitute,
glob and subst-globs-only styles.

It is also possible to call _expand as a function, in which case the
different modes may be selected with options: -s for substitute, -g
for glob and -o for subst-globs-only.
```